# How to populate a populated field from lookup mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

question, answer and profile modals

```
question = {
  _id: "00000",
  question: "",
  category: "gaming"
}

answer = {
  _id: "xyz",
  answer: "some answer",
  questionId: "00000",
  userID: "11111"
}

profile = {
  _id: "11111",
  name: "alex",
}
```

what i want to achieve:

```
{
  _id: "00000",
  question: "",
  category: "gaming",
  usersAnswered: [
    { _id: "xyz",
      answer: "some answer",
      questionId: "00000",
      userID: {
        _id: "11111",
        name: "alex",
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to populate the `userID` field which we get from $lookup

```
question
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        category: "gaming",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "answers",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "questionID",
        as: "usersAnswered",
      },
    },
  ])
```

what should be done to further populate the userID field using $lookup i guess.

Just a bit new to aggregation framework, been using mongoose to get the job done but then this situation came up and had to integrate a field from another collection in question model i.e. `usersAnswered` so i am learning aggregation framework it gets a bit confusing.

Comment: You can use another `$lookup` to populate the user details.

Comment: can u please show me the exact query, i've tried another lookup ofc and not getting the desired result.

Comment: You can apply this lookup on the result of the first lookup. Further search the net for a search-string like "mongodb nested lookups" for similar examples.